# Keeping history of Django model (by using memoization?)

Tags: python, django

I'm working on a Django project for which I'll need to store the historic information of many models.

So far, I'm using the following strategy:

1. Memoize the relevant values in `__init__`.
2. When saving, check if a relevant value has changed.
3. If a relevant value has changed, save memoized values into a "history" model.

My code goes as follows:

```
from django.db import models
from core.models import User

class Spam(models.Model):
    user= models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='spam')
    ham = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    eggs = models.IntegerField()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Spam, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.__relevant_fields = ['ham', 'eggs']
        self._memoize()

   def _memoize(self):
       for f in self.__relevant_fields:
           setattr(self, '__prev_%s' % f, getattr(self, f))

   def _get_prev_value(self, f):
       return getattr(self, '__prev_%s' % f)

   def _dirty_field(self, f) -> bool:
       return getattr(self, '__prev_%s' % f) != getattr(self, f)

   def _dirty(self) -> bool:
       return any([self._dirty_field(f) for f in self.__relevant_fields])

   def _save_history(self):
       history = dict()
       for f in self.__relevant_fields:
           history[f] = self._get_prev_value(f)
       self.user.spam_history.create(**history)

   def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
       super(Spam, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
       if self._dirty():
           self._save_history()

class SpamHistory(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='spam_history')
    ham = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    eggs = models.IntegerField()
```

Although this approach works, there are some things that make me uncomfortable:

1. I need to do this for many models, so I'm repeating myself a lot! I'm looking into inheritance, mixins or the like, but so far I haven't found a right way to make it work.
2. Is this the best approach to achieve what I want? Considering that I will need to fetch historic records frequently, I need the "history" model for each model I need to keep history from.

So, my specific questions are:

- Am I implementing a good strategy for keeping the history of my model(s)?
- Is there a way to improve this strategy by using an inheritance or mixin strategy?

Comment: Third-party tools might exist that will do this for you.

Comment: @FMc I'll search for them (if you know of one, could you share it?)

Comment: @Fmc I've found [django-model-changes-py3](https://github.com/iansprice/django-model-changes-py3); however, it seems that this just saves the current state plus the two previous states of the model instance... I'd like to keep the full history.

Comment: @FMc Ook! I found what I need: [django-simple-history](https://pypi.org/project/django-simple-history/)! Right now I'm feeling a bit dumb I didn't found this earlier.

Comment: @Graipher indeed. Correcting now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, after googling a bit more, I found a possible solution: [django-simple-history](https://pypi.org/project/django-simple-history/):

```
from django.db import models
from core.models import User
from simple_history.models import HistoricalRecords

class Spam(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='spam')
    ham = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    eggs = models.IntegerField()
    history = HistoricalRecords()
```

This seems to do exactly what I need to do. I'll test it.